# Unwind segue stopped working in iOS9 > Freeze with no crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, segue, unwind-segue

I have an iOS application with a main view controller that presents 2 modals in a row.

So this kind of sequence:

VC1 > M1 > M2

I have an unwind segue in modal 2 which I want to use jump back to VC1.  In VC1 I added an IBAction:

```
-(IBAction)unwindFromM2:(UIStoryboardSegue *) unwindSegue
{

}
```

Everything worked fine in iOS 8 and Xcode 6.  However in Xcode 7 and iOS 9, after calling the unwind segue M2, I notice that unwindFromM2 is called but the previous view (M2) doesn't go away and basically freezes.  No error or crash in Xcode.  Looking for advice.

I did directly drag from the yellow view controller icon to the exit icon in storyboard (without associating a button to the unwind).  Could this be the cause?  I have a 2 step dialog for exiting out of the view controller and cannot directly drag an action to trigger the unwind.

Comment: I have the same problem.  Xcode 7 compiling to a device with iOS8 works fine but when compiled to an iOS9 device the unwind does not work.

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround for this problem for iOS9.  I had to do to get the unwind to actually pop the view controller in the unwind code.

```
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(v)  ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending)

- (IBAction)unwindToMyViewController:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue {
    if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"9")) {
        [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
}
```